# How can I extract parameters of curl request and append them to beginning of txt file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, text, append

I have a bash file which is executed every 5 seconds, it goes like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
curl -I http://192.168.100.16:4000/status >> /home/debian2/debian0_ping.txt
```

It pings to a server running in a neighbor Virtual Machine and records the curl response into the specified file "debian0_ping.txt"

but the recorded response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 ok <--- First Ping
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Tye: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Etag: "/2-n009QiTIwXgNt...."
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 18:56:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 ok <--- Second Ping
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Tye: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Etag: "/2-n009QiTIwXgNt...."
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 18:56:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Which is a problem because I need the pings responses to be recorded this way (the most recent on top):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 ok <--- Second Ping
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Tye: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Etag: "/2-n009QiTIwXgNt...."
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 18:56:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 ok <--- First Ping
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Tye: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Etag: "/2-n009QiTIwXgNt...."
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 18:56:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Finally I need to record only the first line (HTTP/1.1 200 ok) and the date line (Date: ...)
I've tried using  SED commands, but it doesn't seems to take variables as parameters to append onto the file.

Please, how can I achieve this, I know it's simple but I'm too new at automating things.

Comment: take a look at [tac](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html)

Comment: You can't append to the beginning of a file, that's just not the way they work. It's like trying to add something on the bottom of a stack. You'd need to create a new file consisting of the new response + the old file, then replace the old file with the new one. Also, selecting out certain lines sounds like a job for `grep`, not `sed`. But what exactly did you try with `sed`, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight-forward way to do reverse the output in `bash`.

To limit what lines you're getting you can use the pattern `grep 'pattern1\|pattern2'`.

You can do something like this to get the output in the desired format.  NOTE: the output file must exist before running this.

```
curl -I https://www.google.com | grep 'HTTP\|Date' | cat - /tmp/blah.txt > temp && mv temp /tmp/blah.txt
```

**Output**

> HTTP/2 200
> date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 20:38:10 GMT
> HTTP/2 200
> date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 20:38:07 GMT
> HTTP/2 200
> date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 20:38:05 GMT
> HTTP/2 200
> date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 20:38:03 GMT